# Can autonomous vehicles be used on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat

Autonomous vehicles seem to be pretty much inevitable over the next 30-50 year. Would their use be allowed on shabbos? I'm pretty sure having to actively call one on shabbos (through an app or whatever) would not be permissible, however there are other possible scenarios:

- Like a shabbos eleveator, autonomous busses go around the city automatically stopping at each stop
- You can schedule an autonomous car to pick you up at a certain time (on shabbos) and drop you off at some location (within the t'chum).

Would it matter what form of energy these vehicles used (electricity vs. combustion)?

Would Maares Ayin be an issue even if these became the standard means of travel by some point?

Comment: Some people do not even use the "Shabbos elevators."